# CSS link setting

Tags: css, hyperlink

When I click on link the link css make change to same css which shows then this link active

I use this  a:visited

But it made changes to the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a style to a:visited it will apply to all links that you have visited unless that link already has a style applied to it that overrides this.

If you want the style to only be applied to certain links you will need to create a new class in your css and apply that class only to the links that it applies to i.e

```
a:visited.mylink {color: #CC0000}

<a href="#" class="mylink">this is your link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the selector in your CSS `a:visited` it will look for all visited a elements in the document, if you want to target one link, use a class:

```
a.myLink:visited
{
   color: #f00;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="myLink" href="#">My link</a>
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but when you use `:visited` it will only activate previously clicked links, to show links in your page just use the CSS selector:

```
a.myLink
{
   color: #f00;
}
```

Hope that at least points you in the right direction.